# If I know Double negation law, De Morgan laws and implication negation is it enough for negating any compound propositions or there are more?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

**I know:**

---

Double negation law:

$ \lnot(\lnot p)\equiv p $

---

De Morgan laws:

$ \lnot (p \wedge q) \equiv \lnot p\vee \lnot q $

$ \lnot (p \vee q) \equiv \lnot p \wedge \lnot q $

---

Implication negation:

$\lnot (p \Rightarrow q) \equiv p \wedge \lnot q$

---

**Question:** Is it enough for negating any compound propositions or there are more law/rules?

Comment: All that you need for negating _anything_ is to stick a $\neg$ in front of it (after possibly wrapping it in a pair of parentheses).

Comment: What about $\forall$ and $\exists$.

Comment: Also, you will need implication $(\implies) $

Comment: If your logic is classical, $\neg$ and one of $\vee,\wedge$ can express every other propositional connective, so you just need those (until you start considering quantifiers).

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima Those don't exist in propositional logic, which is what the OP is asking about (based on their choice of tags).

Answer (score 2):

If by "negate" you mean "put in [negation normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation_normal_form)" - the question is trivial otherwise, since "$\neg\varphi$" is always the negation of $\varphi$ - then the answer is **yes**.

For example, to simplify $\neg(a\wedge (b\vee c))$ we would proceed as follows:

- $\neg(a\wedge P)\equiv\neg a\vee\neg P$.
- Taking $P$ to be $b\vee c$ above, we get $\neg P\equiv \neg b\wedge \neg c$.
- Putting these together we get $\neg(a\wedge(b\vee c))\equiv \neg a\vee (\neg b\wedge\neg c)$.

Of course, **this example doesn't constitute a proof**; to actually prove the result you need to argue via induction on formula complexity.